# how to execute omnisharp from command line to format c# source file?

Tags: c#, formatting, omnisharp

I'm using vscode and its c# extenstion(powered by `omnisharp`) and it formats source file very well.

but sometime I may use some other editors and hope formating the source with the same rule as in vscode,

so I wonder could we use the omnisharp's format function from command line ? 
(I have googled this half a hour but found nothing helpness.)

maybe such as the `eslint --fix **/*.ts` cli.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, I don't know how to interact with OmniSharp from a command line directly.

## dotnet-format CLI tool

However, the [dotnet-format](https://github.com/dotnet/format) tool can be installed to do formatting based on a subset of EditorConfig options. I don't think it has all of the features of OmniSharp formatting, but it's done the trick so far for me. (You can find an example .editorconfig file for C# in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2019#example-editorconfig-file).)

To install, run `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format`. You can then format  an entire project or solution by running `dotnet format` from the project/solution directory, or you can format individual files by running `dotnet format --include path/to/file.cs`.

## Editor Plugins

Another option is to use plugins for various editors. I personally use omnisharp-vim for NeoVim, but there are a few other text editor integrations which you can find [here](http://www.omnisharp.net/#integrations) (copied a few here for reference).

- [OmniSharp-Atom](https://atom.io/packages/omnisharp-atom)
- [OmniSharp-emacs](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs)
- [OmniSharpSublime](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/OmniSharp)
- [omnisharp-vim](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim)